# Paypal Autoreturn For Multiple Sites

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, cs-cart

I have a question about PayPal auto return. I have a customer with multiple sites that all of them use the same PayPal business account. The integration contains both notify, cancel and return URLs which are generated automatically.

In order to activate auto-return, I must submit a URL. Because I have different sites using the same PayPal business account do I have to submit multiple auto-return URLs? or does PayPal check the return URL and override's the auto-return URL?

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs specified in the transaction context (at payment time) override any URLs set in the account.

URLs set in the account are only used when nothing is provided as part of the transaction.

(A current [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) does not use return URLs nor need notify URLs for anything, anyway. They are legacy things, only needed for old integrations used by old software/websites.)

Comment: Thanks a lot very useful your info. I am going to try it.

Comment: You were correct because I provided the return URL it ignored the auto-return URL. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.